# GNUPlot format with additional info

Tags: gnuplot

I have a `.txt` file with ~1000 lines of data. Most lines have usual columns with numbers but some lines will have `=== DISASTER ===` meaning those lines will be special.

So far I have my `xrange` and `yrange` set and I use this:

`plot "evolution.txt" u 1:2 t 'fitness of generation' w boxes`

1. How do I add vertical lines indicating those special events?
2. How do I set the number where my graph meets the y axis? In other words what's `y` when `x` is 0?
3. Is there a way to add a horizontal line with the number of max value? For example the best fitness across generations is `1100` so there would be a dashed vertical line at `1100` of y axis.

EDIT: [SAMPLE](https://pastebin.com/6sR5TL65) of evolution data.

Comment: Add an example of your data with "disaster" lines.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6sR5TL65

Answer (score 0):

I would generate two data files: one keeping only the "normal" data and one keeping the lines where a "disaster" occured. This can simply be done with

```
awk '{ if( $2=="DISASTER!") print NR }' evolution.txt
```

This makes the plot much simpler... If you are happy with this, I can try to answer to the other parts of your question